# How to convert varchar to datetime?

Tags: mysql, datetime, varchar

I have a **VARCHAR** column with fields that look like this:

`Wed Aug 26 16:00 2015`

that i want to covert to **DATETIME**, so it would look like this:

```
2015-08-26 16:00:00
```

Is there any way how I can do that directly in mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: use DateTime::createfromFormat (http://de2.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: `str_to_date()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, did the whole thing in mysql with this STR_TO_DATE(due, '%a %b %e %H:%i %Y')

Answer (score 0):

To convert Date in your given format,First you have to convert date to strtotime then you may convert it in your format like this,

```
<?php
$date = 'Wed Aug 26 16:00 2015';
$strdate =  strtotime($date);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$strdate);
?>
```

Comment: The same as the 1st answer in the duplicate topic...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in PHP:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Wed Aug 26 16:00 2015"));
```

Comment: The same as the 1st answer in the duplicate topic...